# Integrating zxing in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, zxing

I tried in using [link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/implement-barcode-scanner-using-ionic-framework/) to implement qr scanner in phonegap.  I didn't do anything related to zxing so I ended up with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:Didn't find class "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"`

So I started looking to resolve it and found many from Google. But all were driven from native app development perspective. (Most of them are out dated). I mean they are advising to add Java files.

But my app is hybrid variant and don't want to add native flavors.

Is there any alternative which should be hybrid (phonegap, ionic etc).

If no other option, is there latest one which helps me to integrating zxing in Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I realised after a head breaking search. If the mentioned link is followed correctly, then the missing class file will come to lib folder in Android studio. Just we need to add it as library. Then it worked.

Comment: Hi, I am facing this issue, how to fix this with eclipse? Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: How did you get successful with this?